# How can I parse this date in Golang?

Tags: parsing, datetime, go

I am having some trouble in parsing this date (**"APR 19, 3:15p ET"**), can anyone please help me in this regard?

This is the code which I have written.

```
d, err := time.Parse("JAN 02, 3:04p ET", date)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 letter month constant is `Jan`

```
date := "APR 19, 3:15p ET"
d, err := time.Parse("Jan 02, 3:04p ET", date)
```

http://play.golang.org/p/LkeQOtc1Hd

Comment: I am getting this date from somewhere and in the year factor, I am getting "0000". How can I parse it so that "0000" becomes "2016"

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: there's no year in your date, so it's set to 0. You could add the current year after with `d.AddDate(time.Now().Year(), 0, 0)`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: it does work, please show what you've tried.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: you didn't assign the new date anywhere: http://play.golang.org/p/egz1bY-gLi

Comment: Ohh! So stupid of me. Thank a lot kind sir. I really appreciate it! :)